# Why no many-to-many relationships?

Tags: sql, database

I am learning about databases and SQL for the first time.  In the text I'm reading (Oracle 11g: SQL by Joan Casteel), it says that "many-to-many relationships can't exist in a relational database." I understand that we are to avoid them, and I understand how to create a bridging entity to eliminate them, but I am trying to fully understand the statement "can't exist."

Is it actually physically impossible to have a many-to-many relationship represented?

Or is it just very inefficient since it leads to a lot of data duplication?

It seems to me to be the latter case, and the bridging entity minimizes the duplicated data. But maybe I'm missing something? I haven't found a concrete reason (or better yet an example) that explains why to avoid the many-to-many relationship, either in the text or anywhere else I've searched.  I've been searching all day and only finding the same information repeated: "don't do it, and use a bridging entity instead."  But I like to ask why. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the context in which the author makes this statement? I suspect there is more to the statement than what is seen on the surface as M-M relationships are a fundamental design solution. That said, they are implemented as multiple 1-M relations and perhaps that is what the author is trying to say.

Comment: Thomas, the author does explain bridging entities and how they allow a many-to-many relationship to be represented by two one-to-many relationships.  Looks like my quote has started quite a bit of controversy below, but I think it is semantic.  The key word in your post is "implemented."  Obviously what the author meant was you cannot directly implement M-M relationships, as she goes on to explain how to implement them with 1-M's.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around it, but the answers so far are helping.

Comment: If you want to look at the debate below, it seems there is a question of definition.  M-M relationships cannot exist in a single foreign-key definition; that is not possible, BUT... with link tables, M-M relationships are created and maintained, and this is a legitimate use of a relational database system.

Comment: @Johnson - Right. You cannot *declare* a M-M relationship (i.e. via a constraint) but you can *implement* the equivalent.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Think about a simple relationship like the one between Authors and Books. An author can write many books. A book could have many authors. Now, without a bridge table to resolve the many-to-many relationship, what would the alternative be? You'd have to add multiple Author_ID columns to the Books table, one for each author. But how many do you add? 2? 3? 10? However many you choose, you'll probably end up with a lot of sparse rows where many of the Author_ID values are NULL and there's a good chance that you'll run across a case where you need "just one more." So then you're either constantly modifying the schema to try to accommodate or you're imposing some artificial restriction ("no book can have more than 3 authors") to force things to fit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But why would you need multiple Author_ID columns?  Why couldn't you create multiple rows, one for each Author_ID?  I guess to answer my own question... at that point you would have no good PK candidate in the book table, since Book_ID would get repeated when it had multiple authors (unless you made the PK a composite of Book_ID and Author_ID which would seem kind of clunky I guess).  Still, "clunky" is different from impossible.

Regardless, I think I am beginning to understand.  Let me know if this makes sense: (continued below)

Comment: (continued from above) 1-M example: Publisher -< Book : In the Publisher table, you only list Pub_ID's, but in the Book table you list both Book_ID's and Pub_ID's.  This allows the logical PK to not get repeated in either table (no Pub_ID repeats in Publisher table and no Book_ID repeats in Book table).  Pub_ID's do repeat in the Book table, which is ok since the rows will be different for every other attribute.  This leads me to a general rule that an attribute can only be repeated in a "many table" if the other side of the connection is a "one table." (continued below)

Comment: (continued from above) M-M example: Book >-< Author : In the Book table, you can't repeat Author_ID's, and in the Author table, you can't repeat Book_ID's... because of the "rule" I outlined above.  So there is no way to link the tables without creating the bridging table link.

However, what is the result of breaking that rule?  Let's pretend we do. (continued below)

Comment: (continued from above) RULE-BREAK: In the Book table, we have both repeating Book_ID's and Author_ID's.  I guess the problem here is that even though you could use a composite of the two as a PK... it would be silly since there is no row which represents a single book.  You have to combine multiple rows to get all the info about one book.  Same for the reverse (repeating both values in the Author table).  Still, it does seem possible to me.  Just like a really bad idea.  All the info would still be available, even if greatly duplicated and harder to interpret.

Comment: @Johnson: I think I got less commentary than this on my Master's thesis! :-) But I think you're getting the correct understanding now.

Comment: Haha, thanks for reading it all. I guess I am just being a stickler on the definition of "impossible."  I originally read it as the DB would be "impossible to use" if implemented that way.  Seems to me now it would just be a major PITA.

Answer (score 14):

A true many-to-many relationship involving two tables is impossible to create in a relational database. I believe that is what they refer to when they say that it can't exist. In order to implement a many to many you need an intermediary table with basically 3 fields, an ID, an id attached to the first table and an id atached to the second table.

The reason for not wanting many-to-many relationships, is like you said they are incredibly inefficient and managing all the records tied to each side of the relationship can be tough, for instance if you delete a record on one side what happens to the records in the relational table and the table on the other side? Cascading deletes is a slippery slope, at least in my opinion.

Comment: There is no requirement that there be a 3rd "ID" field in that intermediary table. You simple make a composite key from the ID's of the two other tables.

Comment: @PatrickMichalina: I like to use single column primary keys but composite keys do have their uses. I think its very situational. But, yes, for this very basic example you could get away with using the other two columns as a composite key.

Comment: I really liked the first paragraph of this answer. It's categorical where some dozens of articles, posts and answers are just obscure.

Comment: "involving two tables is impossible to create in a relational database" - I recently re-read [Codd's seminal paper](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf) and there's nothing inherent in Codd's Relational Model that would prohibit many-to-many relationships (remember a "relation" is _not_ a Relationship) - Codd's paper leaves the door open to RDBMS implementations supporting _arbitrary constraints_ to ensure consistency, and that _could_ include many-to-many foreign-keys, it's just that (as of 2021) no _extant RDMBS_ supports native many-to-many FKs.

Comment: A single column primary key doesn't enforce uniqueness (of the combination of FKs) like a composite key does. But yes, it's very situational.

Answer (score 9):

Normally (pun intended) you would use a link table to establish many-to-many

Like described by Joe Stefanelli, let's say you had Authors and Books

```
SELECT * from Author
SELECT * from Books
```

you would create a `JOIN` table called AuthorBooks

Then,

```
SELECT * 
FROM Author a 
JOIN AuthorBooks ab
  on a.AuthorId = ab.AuthorId 
JOIN Books b
  on ab.BookId = b.BookId
```

hope that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "normally"? I thought that in M:N relationships a third table is a must.

Comment: @carloswm85 A third-table is required only if you want the RDBMS to enforce referential-integrity. It is not required if you're packing multiple references into a single column in each row (e.g. using Postgre's `array` type, or some hack involving JSON or XML-types) - you should only ever do that if you can guarantee the integrity of the references via some other means. You can then use some unpacking method in the query to synthesize a virtual-table that you can `JOIN` with). I stress that this is still generally a bad idea.

Comment: @carloswm85 I know that it was a long time since your question, but with "normally" he means based on normalization and the normal forms. For example, to be on first normal form, data on each field of a row must be atomic, and it means that data can't be coma separated and those things. Basically, create a third row as you said.

Comment: @GustavoLozada it's never too long for this questions. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

> > it says that "many-to-many relationships can't exist in a relational database."

I suspect the author is just being controversial. Technically, in the SQL language, there is no means to explicitly declare a M-M relationship. It is an emergent result of declaring multiple 1-M relations to the table. However, it is a common approach to achieve the result of a M-M relationship and it is absolutely used frequently in databases designed on relational database management systems.

> > I haven't found a concrete reason (or better yet an example) that explains why to avoid the many-to-many relationship,

They should be used where they are appropriate to be used would be a more accurate way of saying this. There are times, such as the books and authors example given by Joe Stafanelli, where any other solution would be inefficient and introduce other data integrity problems. However, M-M relationships are more complicated to use. They add more work on the part of the GUI designer. Thus, they should only be used where it makes sense to use them. If you are highly confident that one entity should never be associated with more than one of some other entity, then by all means restrict it to a 1-M. For example, if you were tracking the status of a shipment, each shipment can have only a single status at any given time. It would over complicate the design and not make logical sense to allow a shipment to have multiple statuses.

Answer (score 4):

Of course they can (and do) exist.  That sounds to me like a soapbox statement.  They are required for a great many business applications.

Done properly, they are not inefficient and do not have duplicate data either.

Take a look at FaceBook.  How many many-to-many relationships exist between friends and friends of friends?  That is a well-defined business need.

The statement that "many-to-many relationships can't exist in a relational database." is patently false.

Comment: But they are implemented as two one to many relationships which I'm pretty sure is the point of the question.

Comment: No matter how you look at it, it's still a many-to-many relationship, and to claim no such thing exists because you're only looking at one half of a relationship is patently absurd.

Comment: @Jeremy - Yes and no. The fundamental constraints in SQL have no provision for explicitly declaring a M-M relationship. A M-M is an emergent result of multiple 1-M relations to the same middle table. In the root concepts of database design outlined by Codd however, they most definitely exist. As Martin said, I'm guessing the author is being intentionally controversial to make a point about how M-M are actually implemented. (That or the author is a bozo).

Comment: you're addicted to patently. Let it go :) a direct many to many relationship cannot exist in RDBMS. You can't have an array of keys as a column. that is why it cannot work. (at least not natively)

Comment: @Thomas - It might have been in contrast to Codasyl or OO databases but I am getting out of my depth here as I have never used either.

Comment: @JDPeckham: if the quote was " a direct many to many relationship cannot exist in RDBMS" I would agree with you.  That wasn't the quote though. M-M relationships can, and do, and must, exist in relational database systems.

Comment: maybe the semantic difference is between the abstract ER model and its realization as a set of tables, columns, and keys?

Comment: Yes I think we're talking about specific definitions.  I took offense at the generalized statement (possibly taken out of context) about something that is, at the end of the day, simply not true, yet claimed by a subject matter expert to the point of confusing one of his readers.

Answer (score 3):

Many-to-many relationships are in fact very useful, and also common.  For example, consider a contact management system which allows you to put people in groups.  One person can be in many groups, and each group can have many members.

Representation of these relations requires an extra table--perhaps that's what your book is really saying? In the example I just gave, you'd have a Person table (id, name, address etc) and a Group table (id, group name, etc).  Neither contains information about who's in which group; to do that you have a third table (call it PersonGroup) in which each record contains a Person ID and a Group ID--that record represents the relation between the person and the group.

Need to find the members of a group? Your query might look like this (for the group with ID=1):

```
SELECT Person.firstName, Person.lastName 
FROM Person JOIN PersonGroup JOIN Group 
ON (PersonGroup.GroupID = 1 AND PersonGroup.PersonID = Person.ID);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is correct. The Many to Many relationship is broken down into several One to Many relationships. So essentially, NO many to many relationship exists!

Answer (score 2):

Well, of course M-M relationship does exist in relational databases and they also have capability of handling at some level through bridging tables, however as the degree of M-M relationship increases it also increases complexity which results in slow R-W cycles and latency. 
It is recommended to avoid such complex M-M relationships in a Relational Database. Graph Databases are the best alternative and good at handling Many to Many relationship between objects and that's why social networking sites uses Graph databases for handling M-M relationship between User and Friends, Users and Events etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let's invent a fictional relationship (many to many relationship) between books and sales table. Suppose you are buying books and for each book you buy needs to generate an invoice number for that book. Suppose also that the invoice number for a book can represent multiple sales to the same customer (not in reality but let's assume). We have a many to many relationship between books and sales entities.
Now if that's the case, how can we get information about only 1 book given that we have purchased 3 books since all books would in theory have the same invoice number? That introduces the main problem of using a many to many relationship I guess. Now if we add a bridging entity between Books and sales such that each book sold have only 1 invoice number, no matter how many books are purchases we can still correctly identify each books.

Answer (score 2):

In a many-to-many relationship there is obvious redundancy as well as insert, update and delete anomaly which should be eliminated by converting it to 2 one-to-many relationship via a bridge table.

Answer (score 0):

M:N relationships should not exist in database design. They are extremely inefficient and do not make for functional databases. Two tables (entities) with a many-to-many relationship (aircraft, airport; teacher, student) cannot both be children of each other, there would be no where to put foreign keys without an intersecting table. aircraft-> flight <- airport; teacher <- class -> student.

An intersection table provides a place for an entity that is dependent on two other tables, for example, a grade needs both a class and a student, a flight needs both an aircraft and an airport. Many-to-many relationships conceal data. Intersection tables reveal this data and create one-to-many relationships that can be **more easily understood and worked with**. So, the question arises, what table should the flight be in--aircraft or airport. Neither, they should be foreign keys in the intersection table, Flight.

Comment: Your example is an odd choice since `Flight` is clearly an entity in its own right with its own data (e.g. `routeId`, `takeOffTime`) and that needs to be directly referenced through FKs (e.g. by `Ticket`). A better example would be a simple bridging table with no additional data. Some relationships are semantically M:N so claiming they shouldn't exist in database design is misleading - your answer needs to distinguish semantics and implementation.