# Whether to use has_many or has_many :through in a data model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling, activemodel

I am using Ruby on Rails to build a web app, and my data model has users, and each user can create keys (musical keys, e.g. A# minor).

Keys are made up of chords, and chords are made up of notes. There are a finite number of notes, but there are an infinite number of chords and keys (as each user can create their own, allowing for duplicates).

I am currently working under the assumption that keys, chords and notes will each be a table in the database (stop me if that sounds wrong), and I am trying to decide if each of these should belong_to the level above it.

I would like to be able to select a key and see all of the chords in it, and select a chord and see all of the keys that it is in (same for chords/notes). Additionally, I want to be able to see lists (indexes) of users, keys, chords and notes, independent of each other. Does this lend itself towards using belongs_to :through association?

If it wasn't already clear, I'm a RoR beginner, so any guidance/advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a database model for this?  Let me know if you still have any outstanding questions.

Comment: Thanks @Powers, I'm leaning towards using many-to-many relationships between keys and chords, and between chords and notes, but I'm still not sure this is the best way. The reason I'm not sure is that keys and chords can both be created independent of each other, however, keys will always contain at least a few chords. I want to be able to see info about a key (e.g. what chords are in it) and info about a chord (e.g. what keys are it in and what notes are in it). Do you think many-to-many relationships make sense? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `has_many` relationships when there is a one-to-many relationship and `has_many :through` when there is a many-to-many relationship.  For example, in your description, you say chords are made up of many notes, so a chord `has_many` notes.  Does a note only have one chord or does it `have_many` chords?  If the note only has one chord, a `has_many`/`belongs_to` relationship is appropriate.

I just did a Wikipedia search and found that the C major chord consists of the notes C, E and G.  If a chord `has_many` notes and a note `belongs_to` a chord, then the `chord_id` will be stored in the notes table and a note cannot `have_many` chords.  I assume that a note `has_many` chords, so a `many_to_many` relationship is probably more appropriate.

I created a [code quiz](http://www.codequizzes.com/topics/3/quizzes/54) on `many_to_many` relationships that you might find helpful.

Comment: thanks for the response, very helpful. It sounds like I would need many-to-many relationships. Is it bad/wrong to have that many levels of relationships (User -> Keys -> Chords -> Notes), or is that ok as far as best practices are concerned? Also, is there a naming convention that I should follow to name the junction object joining each pair (e.g. chord belongs_to key through: chord_in_key)? Thanks again

Comment: @jackerman09 - I am not sure how notes are related to keys and chords, so it is hard for me to say how to incorporate notes into the database design.  There is no formal naming convention for `has_many through`, but you should name the join model something that describes the relationship.  For `has_and_belongs_to_many` tables, there is a naming convention for the join table, but I don't recommend this type of join.  You are asking the right questions :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anything to add to the earlier answers Ruby wise. This is more a music theory comment on your question than a answer to the programming problem. I've been down your path and learned a few things that may impact your design choices. There is no good answer for how one relates a set of notes to keys because the chord meaning of a sequence of notes is ambiguous. The same sequence of notes can have different cord names (and meanings) depending on how it is used or intended by the composer. The problem gets worse with more complex chords. You can easily go from key to chords to notes but there is no guaranteed way to go backward without picking the brain of the composer. The problem comes from the basic music dichotomy where notes can be defined either in terms of their harmonic relationships (a just perfect fifth having 3:2 ratio) or their position in a tempered chromatic scale. (Tempered perfect fifth as played on a piano is 700 cents or a ratio of roughly 1.498.) The tempered scale is a necessary compromise but when you use it to represent compositions vital music theory information is lost. For all musical intervals in the tempered scale there can be many similar perfectly tuned intervals. For example intervals defined by these ratios: 3:2, 40:27, and 243:160 are all close enough that they translate to the same tempered notes but to know what the chord is you need to know which ratio was intended. Since the tempered note is an approximation once you pick an actual note the ratio information you need to go from notes to chords is lost. It is ratios that define chords in the compositional sense.

This doesn't mean it is an impossible task at least for the simpler chords. With triads there is usually only one useful choice even with inversions but once you add a seventh it gets messy. You have to make choices. There will be a most likely choice which would probably be good enough. I decided to pick the most harmonic possible chord (approximately the chord with smallest integers in the interval ratios.) It means you can't be 100% reliable trying to deduce key related chord names from the notes that make them up. With the average jazz composition (jazz loves complex chords) it pretty much becomes a hopeless case.

If you are just using the data for performance on instruments with tempered tuning it probably doesn't make any difference. In a tempered scale all these chords sound the same. You get into trouble if you are trying to tune A Capella (The human voice is infinitely tunable and tends to go towards perfect tuning) or trying to understand the musical intent of the composer.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answer put forward my Powers. I disagree in terms of having a `many-to-many` relationship in your application. Its **BAD** database design approach to taking this. I believe if you have some sort of `many-to-many` relationship going on you will want to have a resolving table that will store both composite keys `chord_id` and `note_id` this table breaks down the many-to-many relationship and resolves this form of cardinality you'd potentially have going on here. So that effectively you could have a Chord **has_many** notes **through** ChordNote and then in your Note table you would have a Note **has_many** chords **through** ChordNote. You'll notice the keyword `through` the following link explains exactly what this kind of relationship set up does [Has-Many-Through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). I stand correct in defending that having model association Chord has_many Notes and a Note has_many Chords because this SO question defends my reasoning [Why No Many To Many Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339143/why-no-many-to-many-relationships). I just don't see why you you'd go with setting up your application with a Many-To-Many association.

So in saying all of this your set up would be (*thats if you have a many-to-many*)

**Chord**

```
class Chord < ActiveRecord::Base 
   Chord has_many :notes, :through ChordNote
end
```

**ChordNote**

```
class ChordNote < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :chords
  belongs_to :notes
end
```

**Note**

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chords, :through => :ChordNote
end
```

Comment: Thanks @David, I'm trying to stick with best practices (as this is my first rails app). Would not using many-to-many associations here preclude me from doing anything later on? Would I still be able to click on a note and see all of the chords that it is in, and then click on a chord and see all of the notes in it? Thanks again

Comment: Certainly, you could do this by having a loop <% @chordNote.each do |note| %> then from this you accessed the particular note which would belong to that Chord. So if you wanted to access the note for a particular chord you could do something like `<%= note.chord.name %>`. Its along those lines.