# Association many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

My project has two entities `Projects` and `Words`.
So a `Project` has many `Words`and a `Word` can be used in multiple `Projects`.

The `Words` table should only contain `unique words`, so that means if a project will add, a `word` which is already in the `Words` table, in the join table will be added the `word_id` against the `project_id`. Or if the word does not exist it should be added in the table in the association should be added into the join table.

So far I am able to add into tables, a project `name` which is stored into `Projects` table and a keyword `name` which is added into the `Keyword` table.

I am not convinced if my approach in solving this problem is good, also I don't know how to deal with the `has_and_belongs_to_many`(I don't thing that I need a `has_many  through` association, because I don't do anything with the model at this point).

Comment: You should break your many-to-many relationship down into two one-to-many relationships.

Comment: It's explained well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339143/why-no-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should absolutely use `has_many_through` over `has_and_belong_to_many` where possible.  You can use `find_or_create_by` to ensure you only create keywords where not already found:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_keywords
  has_many :keywords, :through => :project_keywords

  def add_keyword(name)
    keywords << Keyword.find_or_create_by(name: name)
  end
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_keywords
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_keywords

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class ProjectKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :keyword
end
```

Now you can easily add keywords using the helper method `add_keyword`:

```
project = Project.create(name: 'My Project')
project.add_keyword('foo')
```

Comment: It might be a stupid question, but how is the join table populated? And because the keywords will be added after the project was created, do I need the add_keyword method?

Comment: @Alex Rails knows how to populate the joins table when you set up your associations with `has_many :y, through: :x`. It will automatically create, update and destroy join records for you when you use the given methods of adding and removing records (see them [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)).