# Many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

Guys I am trying to make a simple ticket generation system for my company as a favor. For now, I have a table called `tblTicket` and another table called `tblEngineer` in my MSSQL database.

My application is in C# windows forms, so on the new ticket generation form, I have many textboxes and a comboBox for assigning engineer which is being populated by `tblEngineer`. Upon ticket generation, all the information entered in this form is stored in `tblTicket` along with `EngineerID` from `tblEngineer`.

It was working great but then my client asked me to add option so that 3 engineers could be assigned on a single ticket.

In the future, I will have to develop a "engineer module" in which engineer will be able to see tickets assigned to him only. It will include a login system for authentication purpose. So if a new ticket is generated and is assigned to 3 engineers, only that 3 engineers should be able to see the ticket and not the others.

How should I go about this approach ? It was really easy if there was only one engineer. Now do I need to make a many-to-many table like `tblAssignedEng` with ticket id and multiple engineer ids? referenced as a foreign key? I haven't much experience with SQL so I am kinda struggling here and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard practice would be this, as an example...

You have a "tblEngineer" table...

```
 tblEngineer
 -----------
 (PK) EngineerId
 EngineerName
```

And a "tblTicket" table...

```
 tblTicket
 ---------
 (PK) TicketId
 TicketDetails
```

You now add a link table called "tblEngineerTickets" (or similar) which references the Ids of both the Engineer and their tickets...

```
 tblEngineerTickets
 ------------------
 (PK) EngineerTicketId
 (FK) EngineerId
 (FK) TicketId
```

So that way, you keep all the Ticket Details and the Engineer details separately, and link them using ONLY the Ids...  the link table would look something like this...

```
  EngineerId | TicketId
 ------------+----------
      1      |    1
      1      |    2
      1      |    3
      2      |    1
      2      |    2
      2      |    3
```

This way, you can have multiple engineers assigned to one ticket, and/or multiple tickets assigned to an engineer.

This is best practice and it gives you the most opportunity for expansion. If you were to just add fields to your existing Engineer tables saying "Ticket1", "Ticket2", "Ticket3" etc... you would be effectively be placing a limit on the code, and potentially you'd have to keep going in to the code to add columns.

Comment: Oh I see, right now I have `EngineerID` in `tblTicket` as a foreign key, should I remove it before adding this `tblEngineerTickets` table?

Comment: Well, just note down which Engineers are assigned to which tickets first or something so you don't lose any of the links ;)
But yes, that's correct, you will no longer need EngineerId in tblTicket, as the EngineerId and TicketId will both be in this "link" table that I mentioned ("tblEngineerTickets")

Comment: Thank you Joe ! I really appreciate you taking time out to help a newbie.

Comment: Not a problem at all, anytime. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! It has helped me to start to grasp the relationships between normalized tables. I've successfully created some tables that connect through foreign keys in the way that I'm expecting, and can add new entries correctly, but I'm a little confused about how "joins" work. If I implement a table the way you explained, won't I get lots of duplicates for each relationship? How would you correctly query that information(for example get a list of all tickets, or get a list of all tickets assigned to a specific Engineer, without duplicates from the relationships)?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest making 1-to-Many relationships instead of making many-to-many relationships. You can accomplish this by having a table that maps between your `tblTicket` and `tblEngineer`. For Example:

```
tblEngineer
-----------
(PK) iEngineerID


tblTicket
---------
(PK) iTicketID


tblTicketEngineerMap
--------------------
(PK) iMapID
(FK) iEngineerID
(FK) iTicketID
```

By doing it this way, an Engineer and a Ticker can be in many maps, making two 1-to-Many relationships, and allowing the functionality you seek.

[Check out this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339143/why-no-many-to-many-relationships) as to why you should try to avoid many-to-many table designs.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, so for example if Ticket having `TicketID = 1` is assigned to 3 Engineers having ID 1,5,6 this is what `tblTicketEngineerMap` will look like? 

`iMapID  1...2...3` -- 
`iEngineerID  1...5...6` --
`iTicketID  1...1...1`

Comment: @adback03: What you suggest is actually not a 1-to-many, but a many-to-many relationship. A 1-to-many realtionship would be a foreign key in one of the two tables, which would be inappropriate for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a column to store different logic values:
check this link http://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/stockageopt/

[image]

[image]

This means that 3 tables are necessary for data manipulation, including a significant cost to the relational query engine.

Are there way to simplify this by integrating all these data within the Member table?

Assign a code to each state:

## Methode 1 : ( use 2 tables )

tblTicket  ( id_Ticket , Engineers )

Engineers( id_eng , other columns)

in tblTicket Engineers you can set multiple value like id_1 - id_2 - id_3 ( 1-2-3) 3 engineers

## Methode 2 : ( use 3 tables )

tblticket ( id_ticket , other columns ) ( primary key : id_Ticket )

engineers ( id_Eng , other columns) ( primary key : id_Eng )

TicketEng ( id_Ticket , id_Eng ) ( primary key : (id_Ticket , id_Eng) )

Comment: The link you provided redirects me to a non-english site :(