# SQL - How to insert records that has multiple values of the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a database based on Pokemon but I'm currently stumped on inserting Pokemon with different moves.

Each Pokemon has a move set, so not just one move, but many. However, as I attempt to insert the Pokemon with its variable-length amount of moves into the table, MySQL ignores the previous ones and only inserts the last move.

In short: how do I insert multiple records of the same Pokemon but with its different move?

[I guess a good similar real-world example would be a Person having multiple email addresses. How would I go about inserting that into a table?]

Comment: 2 seperate tables linked with a foreign key of the pokemon row id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're implementing it as a one-to-one relationship, but what you have is a many-to-many relationship (each Pokemon has many moves, each move can be learned by many pokemon).

What you'd probably want to do is have 2 tables.

```
Table 1: Pokemon
ID, Name, Move1ID, Move2ID, Move3ID, Move4ID, Types etc.

Table 2: Moves
ID, Name, PP, Power, type etc.
```

Then you could use another table which contains all the join information between those 2 tables. You'd have multiple rows containing the same Pokemon ID and multiple rows containing the same Move ID, but the [Pokemon ID, Move ID] combination would be unique.

```
Table 3: PokemonMoves
PkID, MoveID
```

Then you could just do a join from the Pokemon table to the Moves table via this relationship table

```
SELECT * 
FROM Pokemon AS p
LEFT JOIN PokemonMoves AS pm on p.ID = pm.PkID
LEFT JOIN Moves AS m ON m.ID = pm.MoveID
```

There are lots of posts on SO about many-to-many relationships, this looks like a good place to start: [Many to many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505938/many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: Well, you see, I have no way of associating pokemon id to the move id.

Comment: ^^pressed  enter too soon... But yeah, I get the information from pokeapi.co and they don't have a field for which pokemon has what move. But the Pokemon has IDs for what moves it can do. So, I assume it's a one to many (one pokemon has many moves) relationship, based off the data setup by the provider... I'm not sure, I'm new to all of this but thanks for the link. I have to do better with terminology.

Comment: Yes, you do - each pokemon record has an ID, and each move in the move collection has an ID - you might just have to extract them from the associated URLs (or GET the data from the move page).

On that note, if you already have a datasource like pokeapi.co, why are you looking to implement your own? What are you hoping to acheive?

Comment: Okay gotcha. I'm trying to imitate the battling system and implement MiniMax algorithm once I get all of the attributes I deem necessary. I'm coding in Python and have all of the object classes set up. Next step is getting the accurate Pokemon information stored in the database in the format of my classes. This is why I'm here now.

Comment: If you look at the [git repo](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokeapi) for pokeapi, they have all the raw data in [CSV format](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokeapi/tree/master/data/v2/csv).
That would be much nicer than polling them for each and every pokemon/move/etc.

Comment: Yeah, definitely too late for that now. But that's not what I'm going for. I'm working on DB design (plus Python REST and Python-to-MySQL connection) for personal knowledge. I will try your method and report the results.

Comment: No that's fine, keep on with the DB design, but use the CSVs to populate your database where possible so you don't keep hitting the API when you don't have to.

Comment: Ahh gotcha! That would be something to look in to. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do the tables look like?  (and is their structure under your control?)

If you are constrained to a single "Email" field, the only way I see you can associate multiple email addresses with a single record(=person) is to treat the Email field as a comma (or whatever) delimited list.

If you control the structure however, you can switch to a one-to-many relationship between "Person"s and "Email"s - something like:

```
tblPerson
[id]

tblEmailAddresses
[person_id]
[email]
```

You'd query that like this:

```
SELECT id, email
FROM tblPerson INNER JOIN tblEmailAddresses ON
id = person_id
WHERE id = <person you're interested in>
```

Which would return as many records as that person has email addresses.

Hard to say *exactly* how the insert would look without seeing your code/data, but you could do something like:

```
sID = <whatever>
For each sEmail in EmailCollection   
    INSERT INTO tblEmailAddresses 
    (person_id, email)
    VALUES (sID, sEmail)
Next
```

Comment: You're actually spot on with what I'm asking. Sorry for the lack of code (I'm also new to SO). If you look at Zac Faragher's answer, that's exactly the DB setup in regards to what I'm asking. But I have movesID (in regards to your example: emailsID) in Pokemon (re: Person)  table as a foreign key. Your logic sounds better however. I will try that out. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I do control the structure of the table. This is my own personal project.