# How to access data through many_to_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

How do I Access data through this Many_to_Many relation?

Here are my database creations:

The "Useres":

```
class CreateSubgroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :subgroups do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :group

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The relationship:

```
class CreateRtimespans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
        create_table :rtimespans do |t|
            t.belongs_to :subgroup_id
            t.belongs_to :timespan_id
        end
    end 
end
```

The Used:

```
class CreateTimespans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table    :timespans do |t|
      t.string      :name
      t.text        :descrition
      t.integer     :start_h
      t.integer     :start_m
      t.integer     :end_h
      t.integer     :end_m
    end
  end
end
```

How do I for example access the names of all timespans, that belong to one subgroup?
And vis versa, how can I show, which subgroups use a specific timespan?

Comment: Thoughts on why many-to-many is bad news. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339143/why-no-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @user3383458 You asked "How do I for example access the names of all timespans that belong to one subgroup?". Why do you accept Ashish Chopra's answer that does not answer this question? His answer does only list the records associated to the instance it does not display the names.

Comment: I tried to accept both. Both solutions were good. Yours was the perfect answer for exactly my question. But Ashish Chopra answered it the way, I can also use it for more. 
I'm sorry, I didn't see, that it deaccepted your answer. 
For sure, your answer was for this question the best answer.

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad No issue regarding acceptance of his answer, hope my answer also gave you some clarity. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question

You can do whatever find call as long as you get a instance. I get a instance by calling .first on the model.

```
Subgroup.first.timespans.each do |timespan|
   puts timespan.name
end
```

Vis versa

```
Timespan.first.subgroups.each do |subgroup|
   puts subgroup.name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As your code suggest you have got two models as

> Subgroup

and

> TImespan

since there is a many to many relation between them we can use them as

```
# all timespans related to a subgroup
subgroup.timespans # where variable subgroup is a Subgroup object
```

and

```
# all subgroups related to a timespan
timespan.subgroups # where variable timespan is a Timespan object
```