# How to create List of Many to many in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is how my tables look like.

[image]

And my classes look like this

```
    public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();

        }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }




   public partial class Course
    {
        public Course()
        {
            this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

I need two things

A) I need to covert the following t-sql to LINQ to get every student with his/her courses

```
Select Student.StudentName
from Student
inner join StudentCourse on Student.StudentId  = StudentCourse.StudentId 
 where StudentCourse.CourseId in(select Course.CourseId from Course where Course.CourseName ='C#')
```

B) I need to map that result to list of Student type

```
List<Student> StudentsWithCourses = new List<Student>();
```

Comment: You don't need many to many... If a student have a course, you are able to get all student in a course with one to many ( student | course )

Comment: @OrcusZ Thank you  for reply :)  Can you please tell me how can i map that to the list of type Student?

Comment: @OrcusZ weel if one course can be visited by more students and one student can visit many courses (as I would expect), thats many to many..

Comment: hello, I will show u the best way to keep many to many using relation table because It's why you should do if you have many to many to keep your database table architecture correct

Comment: @Petr, yeah i wrote my answer too quickly, but a relation table is necessary ( i don't know i EF create it automaticaly )

Comment: @Lucia could you look i a table named CourseStudent was created ( look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx )

Comment: @OrcusZ Thank you :) i am waiting your code

Comment: You don't need to wait my code, you are using the same model as the code provided in the previous link

Comment: As for B, list of Students will be a list Students without Courses, so the variable name is misleading.

Comment: And you should try it yourself, it is not that difficult.

Comment: @OrcusZ Thank you so much ... i edit the t-sql ... can you please tell me how can i convert that t-sql to linq?

Comment: You can have a look to Marcus Code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the table StudentCourse to your diagram to get ridd of the many-to-many relationship you have between the student and course attribute. Many to many should, in relation databases, be avoided. You can read Joe's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339143/why-no-many-to-many-relationships) on that topic.

If you add the table StudentCourse, Entity framework will identifies that table as a many to many link between Student and Course and hide it from the ERD as it fills no purpose of showing there. Your relations will then be 
visualized as `student*-----*course`(just like you have them now).

To get StudentNames and the students CourseNames (when you have added StudentCourse to EF):

```
var list = db.Student.Select(a=>a.StudentName, a.Course.CourseName).ToList();
```

That will be rendered as the T-Sql you specified.