# How to group attribute values?

Tags: laravel

How to get this result:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->name

    foreach ($product->attributes as $attribute) {
        $attribute->name

        foreach ($attribute->values as $value) {
            $value->name
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
{
    "name": "Product",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Attribute 1",
            "values": [
                "name": "Value 1",
                "name": "Value 2",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->name

    foreach ($product->attributeValues as $attributeValue) {
        $attributeValue->attribute->name
        $attributeValue->name
    }
}
```

And

```
{
    "name": "Product",
    "attribute_values": [
        {
            "attribute_name": "Attribute 1",
            "value_name": "Value 1",
        },
        {
            "attribute_name": "Attribute 1",
            "value_name": "Value 2",
        }
    ]
}
```

**Database**

```
products
--- id
--- name

attributes
--- id
--- name

attribute_values
--- id
--- attribute_id
--- name

attribute_value_product
--- id
--- attribute_value_id
--- product_id
```

**Products**

- Many-to-Many relationship for Attribute Values.

**Attributes**

- One-to-Many relationship for Attribute Values.

**Attribute Values**

- One-to-Many (Belongs To) relationship for Attributes.
- Many-to-Many relationship for Products.

I'm struggling to find solution but failed so i posted here for get some solution.

Please help me.

Comment: A tip: never use a many-tomany relationship, best practice is to create a bridging table. 
Check out this post why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339143/why-no-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: you can accomplish this using eloquent constrain egear loading`with`, `select`, `groupBy` instead of having 3 foreach

Comment: @silver Can you show an example?

Comment: @Nemoko How would you solve this problem?

Comment: @Nemoko what do you mean by never use many-to-many relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output

```
"values": [
    "name": "Value 1",
    "name": "Value 2",
]
```

that is not a valid json, you cannot have an array with the same key, you either remove the key or wrap each value in array to have a key name.

Anyway, you can just define the relationship in your product to pull the **Attribute Values** and have a relationship in your attribute value for the attribute name,

something like this,

**Produc Model**

```
// get the attribute_values assign to products
public function attributeValues() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeValue::class);
}
```

**Attribute Value Model**

```
// get the attribute name assign to attribute value
public function attrName() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class, 'attribute_id');
}
```

You can then query the related relationship and modify the attribute_values to suit your required format.

sample;

assume you have this attribute;

```
[{ id: 1, name: "weight" }, { id: 2, name: "style" }, { id: 3, name: "color" } ]
```

Create your product

```
Product::create([
    'name' => 'Product 2'
])->attributeValues()->createMany([
    ['attribute_id' => 1, 'name' => '1.3kg'],
    ['attribute_id' => 2, 'name' => 'something nice'],
    ['attribute_id' => 3, 'name' => 'yellow'],
    ['attribute_id' => 3, 'name' => 'black'],
    ['attribute_id' => 3, 'name' => 'orange'],
]);
```

Then your product query

```
// eager load attribute values and attribute values name relationship
$products = Product::select('id','name')
    ->with(['attributeValues', 'attributeValues.attrName' ])
    ->paginate();

// modify and format the attribute values according to your needs before returning the products 
// refer to Laravel Collection docs on how you can modify a collection and its data
$products->map( function($item) {
    $item->attributes = collect($item->attributeValues)
        ->groupBy('attrName.id')
        ->values()
        ->map(fn ($group, $key) => [
            'name' => data_get($group, '0.attrName.name'),
            'values' => $group->pluck('name')->all()
        ])
        ->values();
        
    //Remove the original attributeValues data 
    unset($item['attributeValues']);
    return $item;
});
    
// Return the paginated products
return $products;
```

you should get a product data format like this

```
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Product 2",
    attributes: [
        {
            name: "weight",
            values: [
                "1.3kg"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "style",
            values: [
                "something nice"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "color",
            values: [
                "yellow",
                "black",
                "orange"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, you can just append a pre-formmated custom attribute values in your Product model which will automatically loads everytime you query a product.

e.i.
**Product Model**

```
protected $appends = ['attributes'];

public function attributeValues() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeValue::class);
}

protected function getAttributesAttribute() {
    return $this->attributeValues()->get()
            ->groupBy('attrName.id')
            ->values()
            ->map(fn ($group, $key) => [
                'name' => data_get($group, '0.attrName.name'),
                'values' => $group->pluck('name')->all()
            ])
            ->values();
}
```

then you can just use

```
return Product::select('id','name')->paginate();
```

or

```
return Product::find(1);
```

and the attribute attributes will be automatically in the response

the code above uses collection methods [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby), [map](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map), [values](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-values).
Check the Collection [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) for more info

Comment: Looks great. What is values()? Can you write a comment on how it works?

Comment: those are collection methods, remove them one by one and check the output, `values`  will  remove the key added by `groupBy`